# using LIKE and BETWEEN in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, between, sql-like

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[select_User_attendance_master_Date]        
(        
@From_date NVarchar(100),  
@To_date NVarchar(100)            

)        
as        
 begin        
  select           

 Employee_Attendace_Code,        
 Convert(varchar(11),Employee_Attendance.Attendance_day,106) as Attendanceday  

    from Employee_Attendance        
(Convert(varchar(11),Employee_Attendance.Attendance_day,106) between '%'+@From_date+'%'    
 AND  '%'+@To_date+'%')     

end
```

this query is not working it is getting nothing in Attendance_day values are eg 2013-11-28

Comment: I am not sure why you converting date values to `varchar` instead of converting `varchar` to date!!! What is the data type of *Employee_Attendance.Attendance_day*??

Answer (score 1):

Please rethink your question.
LIKE is great to operate over strings but ill not work well for dates.
depending on your data it can return a from date is greater than to date.

Try to use date/datetimes variables, if you receive dates as a string, convert that dates to date/datetime data type and just put that values in the between.

And receive that dates parameters as date/datetime types if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this?
You where missing the `WHERE` clause and I corrected a typo for your first column selected.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[select_User_attendance_master_Date]        
(        
@From_date NVarchar(100),  
@To_date NVarchar(100)            

)        
AS        
 BEGIN        
    SELECT           
        Employee_Attendance_Code,        
        Employee_Attendance.Attendance_day as Attendanceday  
    FROM Employee_Attendance        
    WHERE Employee_Attendance.Attendance_day BETWEEN @From_date AND @To_date     

END
```

Comment: i forgot to paste the WHERE , it was included in my SP,

Comment: between '%'+@From_date+'%'    
 AND  '%'+@To_date+'%')       it is not working i mean it is returning nothing

Comment: As answered by NickvV, you don't put '%' when you use BETWEEN, '%' is for LIKE clauses. Plus dates are not stored as char, using char constructs with date is not very good.